# InRequestScope is not disposing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I'm using Ninject in an ASP MVC project for database binding. In "private static IKernel CreateKernel()", I'm binding a database object like below:

```
kernel.Bind<IDbSession>().ToProvider<IDbSession>(new NhDbSessionProvider()).InRequestScope();
```

This works almost exactly as intended, but some pages on the site use AJAX calls to methods on the controller and it seems like every one of these calls opens a SQL connection and doesn't dispose of it when the controller returns. Eventually this causes the NumberOfConnections on the SQL database to exceed the max and the site throws errors that connections aren't available.

I'm pretty new to Ninject and taking over an existing project trying to make this work without doing major changes. Any ideas what I can do to get these objects to dispose? It seems like they should be automatically doing this already from what I'm reading, but maybe I just don't understand.

If I need to share more code let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Disposable instances are Disposed at end of request processing, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes).

However, the documentation for InRequestScope has a section on [Ensuring Deterministic Dispose calls in a Request Processing cycle](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope#important-ensuring-deterministic-dispose-calls-in-a-request-processing-cycle).

Specifically:

> Use the Ninject.Web.Common package
>
> Manually registering OnePerRequestModule in web.config (e.g. if you're
> not using a Ninject.Web.MVC* NuGet Package)

It is perhaps the case that your instances are being/will be Disposed, but just not at the time you're expecting them to be.

Comment: I believe the SQL connections eventually go away, I'm unclear if that's because dispose finally gets called or they time out on the SQL Server side of things. Its certainly well after the web request completes that this happens.... at least several minutes after. 

If its actually doing what it is supposed to be doing, is there a way to force it to do that sooner?

Comment: Nevermind... your comment about OnePerRequestModule lead me down the right path to find the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems someone commented out this line for whatever reason (it wasn't me). Adding it back resolves the problem.

```
DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
```